# Cannot implicitly convert type List<Class> to List<OtherClass> error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have  an `IEnumerable` of `OrgChartManager` objects and want to convert it to a List in my working Class as a property as below. But I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<;Model.OrgChartManager>'` to
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;ViewModel.OrgElementViewModel>'`

My code is below :

```
  private List<OrgChartManager> myList;
    public List<OrgElementViewModel> ChildrenComboDataset
    {
        get
        {

            IEnumerable myEnumerable  = OrgChartManager.Instance().GetChildrenSerch();
            myList = myEnumerable.Cast<OrgChartManager>().ToList();
            return myList; ////****** Error shows here

        }
    }
```

How can I fix this

Comment: What does `GetChildrenSerch()` method return? Is it non generic `IEnumerable`? Why do you cast it to list of `OrgChartManager`, when property has `List<OrgElementViewModel> ` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type must match what you are returing

So change

```
public List<OrgElementViewModel> ChildrenComboDataset
```

To

```
public List<OrgChartManager> ChildrenComboDataset
```

And it will become:

```
    private List<OrgChartManager> myList;
    public List<OrgChartManager> ChildrenComboDataset
    {
        get
        {

            IEnumerable myEnumerable  = OrgChartManager.Instance().GetChildrenSerch();
            myList = myEnumerable.Cast<OrgChartManager>().ToList();
            return myList; // You are returing List<OrgChartManager>

        }
    }
```